# Example to show that presheaf maps agreeing on stalks are not necessarily equal

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory

We know that if two maps $\phi,\psi : \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{F} $ is a presheaf and $ \mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf, agree on stalks then they are equal. Can we find an example to show that the condition $ \mathcal{G}$ be a sheaf is necessary and that merely assuming that it is a presheaf does not suffice ?

P.S. I am learning elementary sheaf theory and would find it very helpful if someone could suggest a good place where I can find lots of examples and counterexamples. Thanks

Comment: as for you reference request I have found Bredon's Sheaf Theory useful with some nice examples.

Comment: If you still need it:
X={a,b} with discreet topology. Restriction maps: Maps that send everything to zero. Now you can choose what \phi({a,b}) does.